# Count based on criteria - R

Tags: r, count, data.table

I have this kind of dataset:

```
dt <- data.table(diagnosis = c(A,B, C, C),
                 only_2020= c(1, 0, 0, 1), 
                 only_2010= c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                 Both_years= c(0, 1, 1, 0),
                 ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
                 YEAR = c(2020, 2020, 2010, 2020))
```

This dataset shows patients who only have had one of the three diagnosis in either ONLY 2020 or ONLY in 2010 or in both years. In this case ID 2 hav had two different diagnosis in 2020 and in 2010. I need the value ID 2 got in vaiable Both_years for 2020 to be counted in the "only_2020", with the criteria that th diagnosis shall be different from eachother - if ID 2 has diagnosis B in both year he should not be counted in only_2020.

So the wished dataset should

```
 diagnosis  only_2020    both_years
     A          1            0
     B          1            1
     C          1            1
```

I have a large dataset so the criteria should be, that if you have different diagnosis in both years then if you had a diagnosis in 2020 you should also be counted in vairable only_2020 or else not

Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach which uses a complex `ifelse()` statement and checks if `diagnosis` has more than one unique category per `ID`.

The toy example above does not contain a case where we have the same diagnosis for two years, and I wonder, in that case, will there be two rows or just one with `Both_years == 1`?

```r
library(data.table)

dt[, "only_2020" := ifelse(Both_years & (uniqueN(diagnosis) > 1) & YEAR == 2020,
                           1,
                           only_2020),
   by = ID][, .(only_2020 = sum(only_2020),
                Both_years = sum(Both_years)), by = diagnosis]

#>    diagnosis only_2020 Both_years
#> 1:         A         1          0
#> 2:         B         1          1
#> 3:         C         1          1
```

Data from OP

```r
dt <- data.table(diagnosis = c("A", "B", "C", "C"),
                 only_2020= c(1, 0, 0, 1), 
                 only_2010= c(0, 0, 0, 0), 
                 Both_years= c(0, 1, 1, 0),
                 ID = c(1, 2, 2, 3),
                 YEAR = c(2020, 2020, 2010, 2020))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! If there is cases where they have the same diagnosis for both years, then they should not be counted at all